# Spring MVC mapping - Not found 404 error - with Gradle and Jetty

Tags: spring, rest, model-view-controller, gradle, http-status-code-404

Not sure What I am missing here...

Sample Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule/*")
public class ScheduleController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/job", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   @ResponseBody
    public String test(@RequestParam (value = "name", required = false) String name) throws Exception{

    System.out.println("name:" + name);
    return "Yes, I got it, " + name;
   }
}
```

web.xml

```
    <display-name>JS</display-name>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/WEB-INF/spring/js-rest.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

js-rest.xml file

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.js.controller">    </context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config />
```

gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty' 
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'
jar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
               'Implementation-Version': version
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
   testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'

   compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.5.RELEASE'
   compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.5.RELEASE'
   compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.5.RELEASE'
   compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.0.5.RELEASE'
   compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.5.RELEASE'
   compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:3.0.5.RELEASE'

   providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
   runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
}

jettyRunWar.contextPath = ''
```

Controller is in    `src\main\java\com\test\js\controller` folder
`web.xml` is in     `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\` folder
`js-rest.xml` is in `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring\` folder

tried 
`localhost:8080\schedule\job` 
`localhost:8080\<projectname>\schedule\job` 
`localhost:8080\job` 
`localhost:8080\<project-name>\job`

All I get is 404 Not found.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you should have a `*` in the controller path. Try this and see if that works.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/schedule") // removed the /*
public class ScheduleController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/job", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   @ResponseBody
    public String test(@RequestParam (value = "name", required = false) String name) throws Exception{

    System.out.println("name:" + name);
    return "Yes, I got it, " + name;
   }
}
```

Also if you want capturegroups like project name you are better of using `@Pathvariable`annotation like so.

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/{projectName}/job", method=RequestMethod.GET)
   @ResponseBody
    public String test(@Pathvariable("projectName") String projectName) throws Exception{
      ...
   }
```